# Simply connected semisimple algebraic group is a direct product of simply connected simple groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, algebraic-groups, simple-groups

In general, a semisimple algebraic group is an almost-direct product of almost-simple groups. However for *simply connected* semisimple algebraic groups, it holds that they are a **direct** product of simply connected simple algebraic groups.

I tried to find a proof for this, but unfortunately on the internet everybody just states this fact without proof! Does someone maybe have a reference for this?

Kind regards

Comment: For a proof, see Proposition $1.4.10$ [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=V9z2cjHOhVoC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=Simply+connected+semisimple+algebraic+group+is+a+direct+product+of+simply+connected+simple+groups&source=bl&ots=Bf0MwZPFID&sig=b2tkei1T-W9nMWM-XQVahPjJC9s&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj97LbQuvHOAhUkAcAKHVy1DrMQ6AEIRTAF#v=onepage&q=Simply%20connected%20semisimple%20algebraic%20group%20is%20a%20direct%20product%20of%20simply%20connected%20simple%20groups&f=false).

Comment: the tag abstract-algebra should be replaced with algebraic-groups

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know this question is kind of old, but I, too, was looking for the proof of this statement and noticed that the source you cited actually does not contain a proof (at least not as far as I can tell). Moreover, it seems to me that the source cited there (3.1.2 in J. Tits' "Classification of  algebraic semisimple groups") also does not contain a proof of this. Do you know of another source which does contain a proof?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Tit's paper is published in Matematika, 12:2 (1968), 110–143, see [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mat&paperid=464&option_lang=eng). I haven't checked for a proof, but it looks like there is one. Are you sure there is no proof?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually the Mathematika paper seems to be a Russian translation and the original appeared in "Algebraic Groups and Discontinuous Subgroups" (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Boulder, Colo., 1965), pp.33-62. In Section 3.1.2, one finds the statement as a proposition, but I cannot find any proof there or any further reference.